# Google map v2 find if current location lies in circle

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

How to find if current location lies inside a circle on google map v2

Answer (score 1):

Use this, if you want to use geofencing functionality, if thats is your aim in your app.

[Geofencing in android](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have three things:

1. A `Location` object with the location of the circle's center.
2. A `Location` object with the current location.
3. The circle's radius.

Then you can use the method `Location.distanceTo(Location)` and compare the result with the radius.

Example:

So I assume you have a reference to a [`Circle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle.html) in your map:

```
Circle circle;
```

Then, I guess your activity implements [`LocationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) and you use the method `onLocationChanged(Location)` to get notified everytime the location changes. In that method, you can do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Location l = new Location("");
    l.setLatitude(circle.getCenter().latitude);
    l.setLongitude(circle.getCenter().longitude);
    if (location.distanceTo(l) > circle.getRadius()) {
        // outside of circle
    } else {
        // inside
    }
}
```

(Untested code.)

Something like this.

Comment: yeah please share an example

Comment: @MiguelRivera: No, I have not tested it. Also, it's been some time since I wrote it here, but I think it should work.